# Collapse data structure

Tags: rascal

I want to remove the inner keywords **attributes** and **elements** such that the attributes and elements are part of the json object itself. Is there a way in doing this in Rascal for a json file.

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": "\"physics\""
    },
    "elements": {
        "material": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "\"blue\""
                },
                "elements": {
                    "color": [
                        {
                            "attributes": {
                                "rgba": [
                                    -1.2,
                                    0,
                                    0.8,
                                    1
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "\"black\""
                },
                "elements": {
                    "color": [
                        {
                            "attributes": {
                                "rgba": [
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    1
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

I created a data structure that parses key value pairs of a xml file. In the json file I want to get rid of the attributes and elements and use nested objects instead of elements.

In javascript I got this to work.

```
    function collapse(e){
    let elements = {};
    for(const key in e.elements){
        for(const element of e.elements[key]){
            elements[key] = collapse(element)
        }
    }
    return {...e.attributes, ...elements}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a very specific transformation that is only relevant for your particular choice of JSON objects which have "attributes" and "elements" fields for every object. It is a bit puzzling why we have this "double encoding" of objects in the first place, but nevertheless you can remove it with Rascal.

This is a bottom-up transformation that matches the structure of every node and transforms it to another using functions from the `Node` module in the standard library. We need this to be able to create nodes of arbitrary arities, for which there is no syntax yet.

```
import Map;
import Node;

// the heavy work is the pattern match that uses the contract of the 
// encoding: two attributes named "attributes" and "elements", each pointing to another object that encodes a map. 
value transform("object"(attributes=node attrs, elements=node elems)) 
  = makeNode([transform(x) | value x <- getKeywordParameters(elems)<1>],
          keywordParameters=(k:transform(b) | <k,v> <- toRel(getKeywordParameters(attrs));
   
// lists need some recursion
value transform(list[value] l) = [transform(e) | e <- l];

// all other stuff is copied one-to-one
default value transform(value v) = v;
```

I did not test this yet, but you get a general idea. Recursion + pattern based dispatch for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in Rascal using this function:

```
map[str,value] urdfToMap(URDF urdf,map[str,value] result = ()){
for(a <- urdf.attributes){
    URDFValue val = urdf.attributes[a];
    if(string(s) := val){
        result += (a:s);
    }else if(number(n) := val){
        result += (a:n);
    }else{
        result += (a:val);
    }
}
for(e <- urdf.elements){
    list[URDF] elements = urdf.elements[e];
    list[map[str,value]] tmp = [];
    for(element <- urdf.elements[e]){
        if(size(elements) <= 1){
                result += (e:urdfToMap(element));
        }else{
            tmp += [urdfToMap(element)];
        }
    }
    if(e notin result){
            result += (e:tmp);
    }
}
return result;}
```

Comment: This is ok, but it is pretty low level and does not make use of features like splat and splice; you can list match using `[*prefix, elem, *postfix] := myList` for example, and splat it all together in a lis in reverse order again like: `[*postfix, *prefix]`. Also, dispatch between different case is typically done with switch case patterns or alternatives of (local) functions. This would make the code shorter and easier to maintain I think. Assignment in a map that you don't want to override: `result[e] = result[e]?tmp`